# IE7 preventDefault() not working on skip links

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I currently have skip links that jump to the div ids and was using e.preventDefault() to stop the url from changing when jumping to the element but in IE7 and IE8 it doesn't work at all using e.preventDefault() and if I take it out the url changes to the div the anchor tag contains reference to. Is their any fix or way around this?

Here is the code

```
$('body').delegate('a.skiplink-accessible-text', 'click', function (e) {
    //e.preventDefault();
    if (!$.browser.msie) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    var jumpTo = $(this).attr('href');
    $('body').find(jumpTo).attr('tabindex', - 1).focus();

});
```

EDIT: heres a little jsbin example for testing purposes
http://jsbin.com/welcome/20846/edit

Comment: you know the code above is skiping the preventDefault if the browser is msie right?

Comment: You do realize that you are only preventing default if the browser is not IE, right?

Comment: yes i do it was a hack for the time being because i still wanted it to not change the url for browsers that support it... IE doesnt support preventDefault() it will display errors

Comment: I'm not seeing how "IE7 preventDefault() not working" is a valid statement when you are not using preventDefault() for any IE browser intentionally. preventDefault works in IE7 for sure. I'm a bit confused in what you are asking exactly.

Comment: preventDefault does not work for IE it will display an error. Even doing a quick Google search will tell you

Comment: does IE by any chance not pick up "enter" as a click event?

Comment: A quick google search tells me others are misinformed. If you look at the code in the jquery library that handles preventDefault() it is using feature detection the right way.

Comment: enter is not a click event. Its a keypress, keydown, keyup, etc event with a specific key code that you can watch for.

Comment: I don't have IE7, but in IE8, [this](http://jsfiddle.net/9wqTh/3/) works fine.   Using the [full screen version](http://jsfiddle.net/9wqTh/3/show/) to see the URL, it is not changing when I click, use the space bar or hit enter.

Comment: @JohnKoerner Not sure if IE7 triggers a click event with the return/enter key. Its been a while since I've had to support IE7 but its possible that that could be his issue in IE7. IE8 handles it correctly though.

Answer (score 1):

e.preventDefault() will work in IE if your event object is a jquery event object.
The underlining code in jquery for prevent default handles this for you using feature detection as seen in this code snippet (taken from jQuery)

```
preventDefault: function() {
    this.isDefaultPrevented = returnTrue;

    var e = this.originalEvent;
    if ( !e ) {
        return;
    }

    // if preventDefault exists run it on the original event
    if ( e.preventDefault ) {
        e.preventDefault();

    // otherwise set the returnValue property of the original event to false (IE)
    } else {
        e.returnValue = false;
    }
},
```

Comment: hmm interesting In IE7 and IE8 with preventDefault() i cant click or hit enter on the link though i also found out this was an issue tracked on their bug tracker.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting errors in your jsbin in IE 8 when using `delegate`.  I switched it over to `On` and it seems to be working now.  Delegate was throwing script errors in IE 8 which could be a jquery bug.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var jumpTo = $(this).attr('href');
    $(jumpTo).attr('tabindex', '-1').focus();
  });
});
```

http://jsbin.com/epabac/6/edit

Edit:  Delegate was throwing an error because you were using delegate incorrectly.  `On` is still the preferred way to go in Jquery 1.7+.  The correct usage of delgate would have beeen:

```
$('body').delegate('a', 'click', function(e){ // ...  
});
```

Comment: `$('body').on('click', 'a.skiplink-accessible-text', function (e) {...` with the above should work as well and allow you to bind to any future tags as well.

Comment: Alright I'm going to try this as well I thought i did earlier. I was looking through the issue tracker and they did say on solved a lot of IE8 bubbling problems and cancelation.

Comment: haha opps that was actually the code i had for delegate i don't know why i put it the other way

Comment: your example still changes the url too though? I'm trying to get it to not change the url.

Comment: It didn't change in ie8. Is it only ie 7 you are seeing this on?

Comment: I thought it was ie8 but i'll double check soon

Answer (score 0):

Try in IE `e.returnValue = false;`

```
$('body').delegate('a.skiplink-accessible-text', 'click', function (e) {

    if (!$.browser.msie) {
        e.preventDefault();
    } else {
        e.returnValue = false;
    }

    var jumpTo = $(this).attr('href');
    $('body').find(jumpTo).attr('tabindex', - 1).focus();

});
```

Comment: I've already tried this and it does nothing the url is still changed to the div id referenced in the anchor tags url.

Comment: @Erwin e.preventDefault() in jquery uses feature detection rather then sniffing out a specific browser to prevent the default hyperlink behavior. See my answer below.